# Export Model with color - How to save the 3D model with real life colors?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, lidar

How to save the 3D model with real life colors?

Using mesh generated by LiDAR scan, I make an object scanner.
But when I save the model as .obj or .stl, it is colorless.
[image]
[image]

I'd like to save in a format where it retains the color in the model as it does in real life.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74398706/how-to-create-3d-scanning-ios-app-using-photogrammetry-or-lidar/76207146#76207146