# How to create 3D Scanning ios app using photogrammetry or LiDAR?

Tags: augmented-reality

I want to create my own 3D Scanning application using photogrammetry or LiDAR, i want accuracy in scanning small objects. Can you please guide me to create such app from scratch ?

I tried to search how to do it using unity but I couldn't find it. I want an IOS app able to do 3D Scanning

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to 3D scanning on iOS using LiDAR, Apple doesn't provide any api to create a 3D model directly.
Although you can use the scene reconstruction api from RealityKit and process its data to create a 3D mesh that you can later export as obj or usd format.
You can find a very good example [here](https://github.com/TokyoYoshida/ExampleOfiOSLiDAR).
This library contains all the code that you can use to export your 3D mesh and extras such as depth map, point cloud etc.

Remember, Although this repo has a scan with texture option but it only captures the texture for the last frame. I myself am trying to fix it in my free time.

To create a scan with all the environment texture you'll have to rely on the [pcl library](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl) and process your generated point cloud using various point cloud processing algorithms.

Edit: Apple has now introduced an api that can be used to scan textured 3D Models on-device. Its called [Object Capture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/RealityKit/guided-capture-sample)